# Poisson Regression and Linear Regression give the same error

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I'll use the data `azdrg112` from `COUNT` package. The `los` will be the response variable while the remaining three variables `gender`, `type1` and `age75` are the explanatory variables. Here is the plot of the response

```
install.packages('COUNT')
library(COUNT)
data("azdrg112")
barplot(table(azdrg112$los))
```

[image]

The responses seem to be drawn from the Poisson distribution. I modelled it and calculated the absolute mean square error as

```
pois_model = glm(los ~ ., data = azdrg112, family = poisson)
pois_pred = predict(pois_model, azdrg112, type = 'response')
mean(abs(pois_pred - azdrg112$los)) # 2.330834
```

I then tried using Linear Regression

```
gaus_model = glm(los ~ ., data = azdrg112, family = 'gaussian')
gaus_pred = predict(gaus_model, azdrg112, type = 'response')
mean(abs(gaus_pred - azdrg112$los)) # 2.343426
```

I expected that the Poisson Regression would be a better fit then yield a smaller error but why both models output the same error?

Comment: Have you tried this exercise with a dataset where the predictors are not all binary variables?

Comment: Yeah, I tried with the data `badhealth`, also in the same package but it's still the same problem.

Comment: I forgot that the formula `los ~ .` doesn't add the interactions. Fit the saturated model with `los ~ gender * type1 * age75` and you'll get the same predictions with both `glm` with the poisson family and with lm even though the coefficient estimates are not the same (because their interpretation in the models is different).

Comment: I tried but what does it suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. It's all about evaluation metrics and loss functions:

- Poisson regression minimizes the average unit Poisson deviance.
- `lm()` minimizes the mean-squared error (MSE).

Thus: If you evaluate the models with MSE, you can expect `lm()` to "win". Similarly, if you evaluate with mean unit Poisson deviance, `glm()` will win.

Now enters Juan the game and chooses mean absolute error as evaluation metric. Neither of the two models tried to minimize this, so either of them might win.

Try: Run a linear median regression via `quantreg::rq(...)`. I'd expect it to do better because it was fitted to minimize mean absolute error.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I was researching for a while but I still don't get it. Do you mean the Poisson Regression and the Linear Regression have different loss functions and use different metrics to solve the problem? Also, I tried `quantreg::rq(los ~ ., data = azdrg112)` which gave me `2.246941` as its MAE, should I consider it as an error reduction or it's just due to chance?. And what do you mean by "enters Joan the game"?

Comment: *You* used a metric. The two models minimize their respective average loss, which are completely unrelated to your metric.

Comment: So if my goal is prediction and I use MAE as the metric, I should use a method that has an average loss related to my metric? For example a method whose loss function is defined as `sum | predicted values - true values |`

Comment: If it is your aim to minimize MAE: yes, you should consider median regression, which minimizes MAE. If you use MAE just as information, you can fit a Poisson regression. But then don't wonder if another model leads to a smaller MAE!

Comment: What I am actually not sure is: why you get exactly the same MAE. Are also all predictions identical?

Comment: There is a very slight difference in the MAEs and the predictions are not identical but I'd say very close to each other. The same phenomenon was seen in other datasets that I tried.

Comment: That seems okay then, thx!